# How can I run a test in my Perl module's test suite only if the required module is installed?

Tags: perl, testing, perl-module

I want to add a test to my Perl distribution that requires a module Foo, but my distribution does not require Foo; only the test requires Foo. So I don't want to add the module to the dependencies, but instead I just want to skip the tests that require Foo if Foo is not available at build time.

What is the proper way to do this? Should I just wrap my Foo tests in an eval block along with `use Foo;`, so that the tests will not run if loading Foo fails? Or is there a more elegant way of doing it?

Comment: What test module are you using?

Comment: I'm using Test::More, but feel free to suggest another one if it has this feature.

Comment: Look at the answers below but reading the old good documentation of the module you are using should be the first option :-)

Comment: Yeah, once I knew that the feature I wanted was called "skipping", I found it in the docs. I was searching for more complicated things like "conditional execution".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Test::More has an option to skip if some condition is not satisfied, see below

```
SKIP: {
    eval { require Foo };

    skip "Foo not installed", 2 if $@;

    ## do something if Foo is installed
};
```

Comment: Nice and simple. Now that I know about the "skip" function in Test::More, I found the section about it in the docs. Thanks!

Comment: `eval { require Foo } or skip ... ;`

Answer (score 8):

If all of the tests that require `Some::Module` are in a single file, it's easy to do:

```
use Test::More;

BEGIN {
    eval {
        require Some::Module;
        1;
    } or do {
        plan skip_all => "Some::Module is not available";
    };
}
```

(If you're using a test count like `use Test::More tests => 42;` then you need to also arrange to do `plan tests => 42;` if the require *does* succeed.)

If they're a smaller number of tests in a file that contains other stuff, then you could do something like:

```
our $HAVE_SOME_MODULE = 0;

BEGIN {
    eval {
        require Some::Module;
        $HAVE_SOME_MODULE = 1;
    };
}

# ... some other tests here

SKIP: {
    skip "Some::Module is not available", $num_skipped unless $HAVE_SOME_MODULE;
    # ... tests using Some::Module here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation of [Test::More](http://perldoc.perl.org/Test/More.html):

```
SKIP: {
    eval { require HTML::Lint };
    skip "HTML::Lint not installed", 2 if $@;
    my $lint = new HTML::Lint;
    isa_ok( $lint, "HTML::Lint" );
    $lint->parse( $html );
    is( $lint->errors, 0, "No errors found in HTML" );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Also, [declare your test step requirement or recommendation](http://p3rl.org/CPAN%3a%3aMeta%3a%3aSpec#PREREQUISITES) (there's a difference) in the distro meta file. This will be picked up by a client performing the installation. At install time, the user can decide whether to install such a requirement permanently or discard it because it was only used for testing.

Comment: It seems like the `Test::More::skip` approach and your answer are complementary. The `skip` function allows me to skip tests that require a module that is unavailable, while your answer allows me to recommend that the client install the module without making it a hard dependency. If the client that is installing my dist decides not to install the optional testing dependency, will it then skip *all* the tests? Or will it somehow know which tests depend on that optional module and automatically skip only those?

Comment: Or, to put it more simply, declaring an optional dependency is definitely something that I will do, but I don't see how it frees me from the obligation to handle the case where that optional module is not installed.

Comment: Not quite, if it's a test requirement then it *will* be available. But I realise now that's not what the question is about, I misinterpreted what you meant with optional. You are right that the skip check is necessary in that case; I edited the answer to make it so.